# What is the meaning of the radical 手 as a part of character?

Tags: kanji, classical-japanese

I know that the radical 手 means "hand" but I wanna know meaning does 「手」 contribute as a part of a character

If anyone can give me five examples and it could be better if he can bring example with a different usings to this radical please do it.

Comment: Ok i edited the question and the last part is a new question here   https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65213/32763

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
曶壺蓋
[集成9728](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9728&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「手{しゅ}」is a picture of a hand. It has variants

- 「扌」(normally written on the left)
- 「⿻一十」(bottom component of「奉」)

---

「手・扌・⿻一十」normally contributes one of two meanings:

1. *Something to do with a hand (anatomy)*, e.g.:

   - 掌 (*palm of hand*)
   - 拳 (*fist*)
   - 指 (*finger*)
2. *Verbs which (probably) involve hands.* There's an endless list of these:

   - 損 (*to harm*)
   - 撃 (*to attack*)
   - 投 (*to throw*)
   - 択 (*to choose*)
   - 抱 (*to hug*)

     ...

---

When「手・扌・⿻一十」contributes *meaning*, it is functionally equivalent to the following components when they also only contribute *meaning*:

- 「又{う}・⿻コ一・彐」(*picture of a right hand*)

  ## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image]
  [後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.5.15
  [合集24506](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=24506&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
  簡
  [image]
  睡・日甲36</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「寸{すん}」(*picture of a right hand with a mark at the wrist*)

  ## <kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
  [image]
  [睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)51</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「{さ}・」(*picture of a left hand*)

  ## <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)950
  [合集28882](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28882&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  三年師兌簋
  [集成4318](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4318&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>
- 「爪{そう}・爫」(*side view of a hand with the fingers pointing downwards*)

  ## <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3471</kbd>
  　
  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image]
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
  　<kbd>今
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

Of course, these components all have different pronunciations, so if these components happen to contribute *sound* instead, then they are no longer equivalent to each other.

---

**References:**

- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究{{kr:所}}《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Comment: Droooze you are the best guy to answer japanese language questions ..your answer is very clear and full

Comment: @user32763 I don't answer Japanese language questions, I answer *kanji* questions. There's a difference! Anyway, thanks for the kind words, glad to help.

Comment: So you are the best guy to answer kanji question ❤