# What is the meanings of kanji 手 when it's part of a compound word?

Tags: kanji

The kanji 手 (not the radical) is very common and i found hundreds of vocbularies are containing it and i thought that its using as a component in words is to refer to ( hand, ability, skill or possession) but i found some words that have this kanji but its meaning isn't from this list so i wanna know all real uses of this kanji and example for each.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手 【て】 Meanings list : hand, arm, forepaw, foreleg, handle, hand, worker, help, trouble, care, effort, means, way, trick, move, technique, workmanship, hand, handwriting, kind, type, sort, one's hands, one's possession, ability to cope, hand (of cards), direction, move (in go, shogi, etc.)

Examples for words containing 手 :

1- 手【て】がける to make, to do, to produce, to work on.

2- 逆手 【ぎゃくて】 underhand grip, backhand grip (e.g. in tennis), unexpected twist, turning the tables (on an opponent)

3- 担 【にな】い手 【て】 bearer, carrier, person bearing responsibility, person in charge.

**Find more about :**

1. [Words starting with 手](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%89%8B)
2. [Words ending with 手](https://jisho.org/search/*%E6%89%8B)
3. [Words containing 手](https://jisho.org/search/*%E6%89%8B*)