# What is the etymology of the kanji 寺?

Tags: kanji, etymology

This kanji has : - 
止(phonetic) + 寸(hand : semantic) and the 止 part became 土 later

But I found in some resources this interpretations which explain "止" function in the kanji so I wanna know which on from this interpretations right or not?

1 : 
"寺　(6)　ジ；てら
The relevant oracle bone form of this character is 止# (stand straight) + 寸 hand/action indicator → 
stand straight by in attending on a superior, then carry out orders → government office (← place 
where official functions are carried out). (Buddhist) *temple* "

2:
Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]: 
Component 寺 from (rem- 土 tǔ) from foot-moving-zhi 之㞢 zhǐ and hand-measure-cun 寸 cùn. (name- hand-foot-si 寺 sì)

Decomposition notes 字形分解说明 [?]: 
(- measurement of time historically done at a temple)

Comment: What references?  What sources are you quoting?  Can you tell us where your quotes and paraphrases come from, and can you use quote markdown to show which text is quoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「[寺]{じ}」was originally constructed from semantic「又」(*[right] hand*) and phonetic「[之]{し}」, indicating the meaning *to hold*.「又」was later replaced by「寸」(*hand with a mark at the wrist*), which is a [synonymous semantic component](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65190/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-radical-%E6%89%8B-as-a-part-of-character/65215#65215).

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_inscription)
[image]
伯寺簋
[集成4007](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4007&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
　<kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

The meaning *temple* is a phonetic loan, and *to hold* is now written as「持」, formed by adding another *hand*「手・扌」onto「寺」.

<kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
金
[image]
邾公牼鐘
[集成150](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=150&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
說文解字</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

> Note:「之」and「止」are very easily confused.「[之]{し}」originally meant *to go*, and was originally constructed from simultaneously semantic and phonetic「[止]{し}」(*picture of a foot*) *walking away from a place* (the *place* is abstractly represented by a *horizontal line*「一」).
>
> Compare the following two glyph evolution sequences, taken around the same time period:
>
> <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1440
> [合集31080](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=31080&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 琱生簋
> [集成4292](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4292&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [語1](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・105</kbd>
> 　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・為](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)23</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)16.1
> [合集11654](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=11654&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 小克鼎
> [集成2798](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2798&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>楚
> [帛](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript)
> [image]
> [帛乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)5.34</kbd>
> 　<kbd>秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)141</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> The bottom-most horizontal line「一」started being written as「乀」in「之」, while a confusingly similar bottom horizontal line started appearing in「止」.

Comment: But I still wanna know which explaination is right Especially the first one...

Comment: @user32763 well, they're all wrong according to my references. (A) `止(phonetic) + 寸(hand : semantic)...` the character contains「之」, not「止」. (B) `"寺　(6)　ジ；てら The relevant oracle bone form...` there is no oracle bone form of「寺」, again it contains「之」and not「止」, and the meaning *temple* is a phonetic loan, not its original meaning. The original meaning of「寺」is「持」. (C) `Character decomposition 字形分解 [?]: Component 寺...` well, the character decomposition is correct (apart from forgetting the mention that it was originally「又」and not「寸」), but again「寺」did not have anything to do with *temple*.